# All URL query throught one file

Tags: php, url, get

Is it real to set that all query will be automatically throught one file ?
For example now i have something like `mysite.com/index.php?contacts` , but is it real to set visually something like `mysite.com/contacts` and that it was the same as `index?contacts` ? If somebody will enter in URL `mysite.com/address` that it will be automatically go to index.php file and word 'address' will be like GET query ?

Comment: You will have to use something like `mod_rewrite` for this to work. http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

Comment: Thanks, didnt know about it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are mentioning is referred to as URL Rewriting.
If you are using Apache, you use `mod_rewrite`. [Here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) you can find detailed information about it.